# Trying to return results from twitter in my django app but I get nothing

Tags: python, django, twitter

I am Trying to return results from twitter in my django app but I get nothing. I'm following tutorial example. Today is the first day I've tried to use twitter and django.
this is my code in my view

```
import twitter

    CONSUMER_KEY = 'CONSUMER_KEY'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'CONSUMER_SECRET'
    OAUTH_TOKEN = 'OAUTH_TOKEN'
    OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = 'OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET'
    auth = twitter.oauth.OAuth(OAUTH_TOKEN, OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET,
                               CONSUMER_KEY, CONSUMER_SECRET)
    twitter_api = twitter.Twitter(auth=auth)

    WORLD_WOE_ID = 1
    US_WOE_ID = 23424977

    world_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=WORLD_WOE_ID)
    us_trends = twitter_api.trends.place(_id=US_WOE_ID)



    context = {

        "api": world_trends
    }
```

this is in my template
    in html
        {{api}}

I also tried

```
{% for a in api %}
    {{a}}
{% endfor %}
```

and still nothing. Is their something wrong with my syntax?

Just to be clear is the following correct?

```
    CONSUMER_KEY = '    Consumer Key (API Key)'
    CONSUMER_SECRET = 'Consumer Secret (API Secret)'
    OAUTH_TOKEN = 'Access Token'
    OAUTH_TOKEN_SECRET = '  Access Token Secret'
```

thanks

Comment: When in doubt, get out of the server/template/client swamp and run it as standalone code so you can debug it. If it doesn't work standalone, then the rest is moot.

Comment: @PeterRowell hello. It works in the shell

Comment: Ah! Then I'll bet this is an object whose str() is something like <foo ...>. That is invalid HTML, so the browser doesn't render it. View the source of the page and see what's there. Or, try doing {{ a.some_valid_attribute }} and see what you get.

Answer (score 0):

If your twitter API is not already installed, use:-

```
python -m pip install python-twitter
```

The Following code will show the US trends:-

```
import twitter
api = twitter.Api(consumer_key="your consumer_key",
                  consumer_secret="your consumer secret",
                  access_token_key="your access_token_key ",
                  access_token_secret="your access_token_secret")
trends=api.GetTrendsWoeid(23424977)
for x in trends:
    print x.name
```

For getting the application secret codes, please visit [this link](https://apps.twitter.com/) and setup your application.

Once the setup is done, click the application and paste all the codes from  there to the respective consumer_key, consumer,secret etc. fields in the above code. The screenshot below, shows from where you can copy the codes.

[image]